# Как сделать валидацию многоступенчатой формы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

```
https://jsfiddle.net/njg0op95
```

Есть форма, состоящая из 5 шагов, на каждом шаге нужно выбрать один вариант ответа. Как сделать валидацию на каждом из шагов, чтобы нельзя было нажать кнопку далее, пока не выбран вариант ответа на данном шаге? На данный момент проверка идет только по последнему вопросу. Если ответ на последний вопрос выбран, а на предыдущие нет, то форма отправляется, а такого быть не должно. Как заблокировать кнопку далее на каждом из шагов до момента выбора варианта ответа? Ведь кнопка submit есть только на 5 шаге, а остальные просто кнопки перехода?

```
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent().parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($(".fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'relative'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 0, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent().parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($(".fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 0, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    console.log("submit");
  //return false;

})
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Валидация_формы

Comment: Вам нужны функции для валидации каждого шага отдельно. Валидация формы же итоговая это && валидаций каждого шага.